# Python binary search tree bug

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have been trying for the last 2 days to implement a binary search tree in python.

Tree node:

```
class tree_node:
    def  __init__(self,val,rightChild,leftChild):
        self.val = val
        self.rightChild = rightChild
        self.leftChild = leftChild
```

Binary search tree:

```
class binary_tree:
    def __init__(self,baseNode):
        self.baseNode = baseNode        
    def addTreeNode(self,treeNode):
        current = self.baseNode
        prev = None
        while current:
            prev = current
            if treeNode.val<current.val:
                current = current.rightChild
            elif treeNode.val>current.val:
                current = current.leftChild
        if treeNode.val<prev.val:
            prev.rightChild  = treeNode
        elif treeNode.val>prev.val:
            prev.leftChild = treeNode
    def print_tree(self):
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
                 print("",node.val)
                 dfs(node.rightChild)         
                 dfs(node.leftChild)              
        dfs(self.baseNode)
    def deleteNode(self,treeNode):
        current = self.baseNode
        prev = None
        while current:
            prev = current
            if treeNode.val<current.val:
                current = current.rightChild
                if current == treeNode:
                    break
            elif treeNode.val>current.val:
                current = current.leftChild
                if current == treeNode:
                    break
        if not  current.rightChild and not current.leftChild:
            if current == prev.rightChild:
                prev.rightChild = None
                current = None
            elif current == prev.leftChild:
                prev.leftChild = None
                current = None          
        elif (current.rightChild and not current.leftChild) or (current.leftChild and not current.rightChild):
            if current.val>self.baseNode.val:
                if not current.leftChild:
                    prev.leftChild = current.rightChild
                    current = None
                else:
                    prev.leftChild = current.leftChild
                    current = None
            elif current.val<self.baseNode.val:
                if not current.leftChild:
                    prev.rightChild = current.rightChild
                    current = None
                else:
                    prev.rightChild = current.leftChild
                    current = None
        elif current.rightChild and current.leftChild:
             if  current == prev.rightChild:                
                prev.rightChild = current.rightChild
                prev.rightChild.rightChild = current.leftChild
                current= None                                      
             elif current == prev.leftChild:
                prev.rightChild = current.rightChild
                prev.rightChild.rightChild = current.leftChild
                current = None
```

I put these tree nodes in the binary search tree:

```
zero = tree_node(0,None,None)
minusone = tree_node(-1,None,None)
one = tree_node(1,None,None)
minustwo = tree_node(-2,None,None)
two= tree_node(2,None,None)
three= tree_node(3,None,None)
minussevenhalves= tree_node(-7/2,None,None)
four= tree_node(4,None,None)
minusfour= tree_node(-4,None,None)
minusfive= tree_node(-5,None,None)
minusonehalf = tree_node(-1/2,None,None)
onehalf = tree_node(1/2,None,None)
six = tree_node(6,None,None)
threehalves = tree_node(3/2,None,None)

bst = binary_tree(zero)
bst.addTreeNode(one)
bst.addTreeNode(two)
bst.addTreeNode(minusonehalf)
bst.addTreeNode(minustwo)
bst.addTreeNode(minusone)
bst.addTreeNode(three)
bst.addTreeNode(minusfive)
bst.addTreeNode(minussevenhalves)
bst.addTreeNode(four)
bst.addTreeNode(minusfour)
bst.addTreeNode(onehalf)
bst.addTreeNode(six)
bst.addTreeNode(threehalves)
```

I succesively print the tree and delete a node to see if my code is correct:

```
bst.print_tree()
Output:0
-0.5
-2
-5
-3.5
-4
-1
 1
 0.5
 2
 1.5
 3
 4
 6
print("Removing node with value -2")
bst.deleteNode(minustwo)
bst.print_tree()
Output:0
-0.5
-5
-1
-3.5
-4
 1
 0.5
 2
 1.5
 3
 4
 6
 print("Removing node with value -7/2")
 bst.deleteNode(minussevenhalves)
 bst.print_tree()
 Output:0
 -0.5
 -5
 -4
 -3.5
 -4
  1
  0.5
  2
  1.5
  3
  4
  6
  print("Removing node with value 4")
  bst.deleteNode(four)
  bst.print_tree()
  Output: 0
  -0.5
  -5
  -4
  -3.5
  -4
   1
   0.5
   2
   1.5
   3
   6
```

So as you can see there is a problem when deleting a item with 1 child in the right side of the tree.

So I went investigating the problem.And I realised that the node with val -1 has 2 children but the
2nd child doesnt appear before trying to delete the node with val -7/2.What is going on here?